# Jquery setInterval() on Bootstrap Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, setinterval

My goal is to animate Bootstrap's progress bar so that is increments by 5% each 50 ms, however I want it to pause for 1500 ms at 25%, 55% and 85%. Here's what I tried, however it pauses at 25% but not at 55% and 85%.

```
var value = 5;
setInterval( function() {
    $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value );
    if ( value == 25 || value == 55 || value == 85 ) {
        setInterval( function() {
            value += 5;
        }, 1500 );
    } else {
        value += 5;
    }
}, 50 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't stop since you have nested intervals. Each of the intervals execute independently until they're cleared.

Even if the proggress-bar is at 25%, it's frozen for 1500ms but the main interval still executes - setting a new (nested inside `if` statement) interval every 50ms (30 new intervals in the time of 1500ms break).

This part of your code is executing 30 times when the proggress-bar is at 25%:

```
    setInterval( function() {
        value += 5;
    }, 1500 );
```

You could use `setTimeout` instead:

```
var value = 0;

function barAnim(){
    value += 5;
    $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value );    
    if ( value == 25 || value == 55 || value == 85 ) { 
        return setTimeout(barAnim, 1500); 
    }
    return value >= 100 || setTimeout(barAnim, 50);
}

barAnim();
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jb16c4ny/)

---

Alternatively, because the bootstrap proggress-bar is *"self-animated"*, use direct stop points instead of updating it every 50ms:

```
var stops = [25, 55, 85, 100];
$.each(stops, function(index, value){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $( ".progress-bar" ).css( "width", value + "%" ).attr( "aria-valuenow", value ); 
    }, index * 1500);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uap25xw6/)